# I am trying to insert data by seeding using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using spaite laravel permission and i am trying to insert data in permission by seeding but unfortunately i am getting error please help me thanks.

getting error when i execute command

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `permissions` (`name`, `0`, `1`, `guard_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Users, parent_id, 1, web, 2021-01-01 09:58:08, 2021-01-01 09:58:08))
```

i need data in permission table like this

permissions table

Note :- parent_id has default 0 in permission table

```
id | parent_id | name 
1     0        | User Management   
2     1        | Users   
3     2        | add   
4     2        | edit   
5     2        | delete
```

**PermissionsRolesSeeder**

```
  public function run()
        {
            // Reset cached roles and permissions
            app()[PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();
    
            // // create permissions
         $userManagementMenu =  Permission::create(['name' => 'Users Management']);
        $userMenu = Permission::create(['name' => 'Users', 'parent_id',$userManagementMenu>id]);
            Permission::create(['name' => 'add', 'parent_id', $userMenu->id]);
            Permission::create(['name' => 'delete', 'parent_id', $userMenu->id]);
            Permission::create(['name' => 'edit', 'parent_id', $userMenu->id]);
            Permission::create(['name' => 'status', 'parent_id', $userMenu->id]);
    
        }
```

Comment: Bro you have added 0 and 1 as column. Remove those

Comment: ok i have found error thanks.

Comment: It should be like this Permission::create(['name' => 'Users' ,'parent_id' => $userManagementMenu>id]);

Comment: it's working perfectly